# how to remove bootstrap modal underline?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

when I use the bootstrap's modal like this:

```
<style>
.modal-content {
  border-radius: 60px;
}
</style>

<div id="upload-loading" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button id="loadingClose" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Upload in progress...</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it shows an underline

I tried to add this style

```
<style>
.modal-content, .modal-content * {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
</style>
```

but it doesn't seem to make any difference..

Comment: Please, upload your image to stackoverflow.com becouse the link in your post is wrong.

Comment: Are you able to see that CSS rule added, when you inspect that <div> element using the Developer Tools of your browser?

Comment: The code you've provided does not duplicate the issue you describe. The text in the modal is not underlined, even without the style change you attempted. Please provide enough code to demonstrate your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .modal-content {border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16317053)

Answer (score 0):

Just give border to the class `.modal-header`

**I just solve it in React**

```
<div>
        {/* Button trigger modal */}
        <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
          Launch demo modal
        </button>
        {/* Modal */}
        <div className="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabIndex={-1} role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div className="modal-content">
              <div className="modal-header" style={{border:"1px solid #fff"}}>
                <h5 className="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Buy Premium</h5>
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-body">
                <p>Your account is limited to only 3 CV views. 
                To review more, purchase Premium Subscription</p>
                <button className="btn btn-primary">Purchase</button>
              </div>
              <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: The question is about a bootstrap modal, your answer is using React, two completely different tools.

Comment: @ARLCode I think he mean that he fixed Boostrap Model issue ut in React.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour, maybe, but I guess us discussing the question just kind of shows how unclear it is haha.

Comment: @ARLCode I agree with you; I think it is not a bit unclear. If haroon sultan can improve his answer by adding good description; I think it will be better.